# Quickly open/switch Visual Studio Solutions

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know about a plugin (or built-in) functionality for quickly switching Visual Studio Solutions?

I'm working in a multi-solution project and need to switch the solution quite often (by reusing one of the open Visual Studio instances)

Any ideas?

If not, how hard would it be to write a plugin on my own?

Comment: Can't you just open multiple VS instances? Why would you want to unload a solution every time you switch?

Comment: `File->Recent Projects and Solutions` aka `Alt-f-j-<number>`? can't think of anything that would achieve that faster

Answer (score 0):

You can add solutions to favorite links with my [Favorite Documents](http://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension.